# tsconfig - How to ignore @types/whatever/node_modules for a specific directory?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings, yarnpkg

I'm running angular 1.5 with typescript (yay), and we include both `@types/angular` and `@types/angular-mocks`.

The trouble is that `@types/angular-mocks` lists `@types/angular` as a dependency with * versioning. This causes yarn to install 1.6 in `@types/angular-mocks/node_modules`.

The final result is a ts compile error: `@types/angular` 1.5 has a different definition for $inject than `@types/angular` 1.6

How can I get the tsconfig to ignore `@types/angular-mocks/node_modules`?

Here is my current tsconfig:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "lib": [
            "es2016",
            "dom"
        ],
        "rootDir": "app/modules",
        "mapRoot": "/modules/",
        "sourceRoot": "/modules",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types"],
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": [
                "app/modules/*"
            ]
        }
    },

    "include": [
        "./node_modules/@types",
        "./typings-custom/*.d.ts"
    ],

    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: for now, i am running rimraf in postinstall...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to exclude \`node\_modules/@types/\*\*/node\_modules\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530597/how-to-exclude-node-modules-types-node-modules)