# How to exclude `node_modules/@types/**/node_modules`?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, tsconfig

I have run into a situation where a type definition in `node_modules/@types` is installing its own @types dependencies, and these "nested" @types conflict with my top level @types.

```
@types
|-angular //v1.5
|-angular-ui-bootstrap
  |-node_modules
    |-@types
       |-angular //v1.6
```

#### How can I exclude `node_modules/@types/**/node_modules` in my tsconfig?

One caveat - I am using awesome-typescript-loader, which [may have some limitations](https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/492).

**What I've tried:**

1 - file glob in the `exclude` property to exclude the nested node_modules

```
    compilerOptions.exclude: '../node_modules/@types/**/node_modules'
```

2 - declaring `types` explicitly

```
    compilerOptions.types: ['angular', 'angular-ui-bootstrap']
```

3 - file glob in the `typeRoots` to exclude nested node_modules

```
    compilerOptions.typeRoots: ['../node_modules/@types/**/!(node_modules)']
```

**What I've learned**

1 - exclude doesn't seem to work with @types

2 - including a type with "types" means including its dependent @types

3 - typeRoots doesn't seem to work with file globs (or I'm writing the glob wrong)

**Related:**

[Exclude @types typings in installed dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704043/exclude-types-typings-in-installed-dependencies?rq=1)

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9731

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11917

https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader/issues/492

[tsconfig - How to ignore @types/whatever/node_modules for a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427807/tsconfig-how-to-ignore-types-whatever-node-modules-for-a-specific-directory)

**Details on my environment**

"node": "8.6.0",
"typescript: "2.8.3",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "5.0.0",
"webpack": "4.8.3",

Comment: Have you tried just updating your version to 1.6?

Comment: @TimBJames  Haven't tried upgrading, although I wish I could! This is for a sprawling AngularJS application that still uses `ngController` in some parts. I'm hoping for a solution that I can implement now, without coordinating with teammates and doing extensive regression testing.

Comment: I hacked a solution in the package.json, but I would still like to know how conflicting dependencies can be obviated.   ` "postinstall": "node rimraf.js node_modules/@types/angular-ui-bootstrap/node_modules"`

Comment: I think the issue isn't going to be easy to resolve due to the different dependency versions. Looks like `angular-ui-bootstrap` is always going to want the later version of the types.

Answer (score 5):

A solution I found for this was to specify the `node_modules/@types` directory in the `tsconfig.json` `paths` setting.

Here's the snippet I changed in my `tsconfig.json`, which you should be able to adapt for your use case. I needed to modify my `baseUrl` and my `paths` settings.

```
   ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "*": ["./node_modules/@types/*"]
    }
   ...
```

In my case I'm using absolute urls in my TS project, so my local files are all relative to `@/`. I think if you are not using an absolute url like that, you should have something like the following for your config:

```
   ...
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["./src/*", "./node_modules/@types/*"]
    }
   ...
```

Here's my complete `tsconfig.json`, which probably has a lot of irrelevant information, for reference.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "checkJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "*": ["./node_modules/@types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*", "*"],
  "exclude": ["build", "node_modules", "coverage"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [peerDependencies](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) to ensure you only have one version of a dependency.

i.e. If I am using typings for angular and angular-mocks, angular-mocks will have its own @types/angular

```
@types/angular  // => 1.5.8
@types/angular-mocks // => 1.5.8
@types/angular-mocks/node_modules/@types/angular // => *
```

To prevent two version of `@types/angular` from being installed, declare `@types/angular` as a peerDependency in your package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `postinstall` script in your package.json:

```sh
for d in node_modules/@types/*/ ; do
  rm -rf ${d}node_modules
done
```

This will loop through the `@types` and remove unwanted transitive type dependencies.